# How to pivot a table in MySQL using case statements?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot a table in MySQL using case statements.  This question has been asked many times here, and I have studied all of those answers, but I am looking for a solution that: 
1. Uses case statements.  Not self joins, subqueries, or unions.
2. Uses just SQL.  Not Excel or shell scripts.
3. Works on MySQL.

Here is the table:

```
create table client (
  name varchar(10),
  revenue int(11),
  expense int(11)
);

insert into client (name, revenue, expense) values ("Joe", 100, 200);
insert into client (name, revenue, expense) values ("Bill", 300, 400);
insert into client (name, revenue, expense) values ("Tim", 500, 600);

mysql> select * from client;
+------+---------+---------+
| name | revenue | expense |
+------+---------+---------+
| Joe  |     100 |     200 |
| Bill |     300 |     400 |
| Tim  |     500 |     600 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to pivot the table to this:

```
+-----+------+-----+
| Joe | Bill | Tim |
| 100 | 300  | 500 |
| 200 | 400  | 600 |
+-----+------+-----+
```

How can I accomplish this?

I have already seen the solutions at artfulsoftware dot com and buysql dot com, but those solutions are not working for my table.

Comment: You can't. Not according to your limitations.

Comment: Jeff, Which limitation prevents the solution?

Comment: You need to use a union because you are aggregating on two different columns (revenue and expense).

Comment: I'm not saying you can't accomplish what you need, I just don't understand why you're placing these limitations on yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, please show me how this could be done with case statements and unions?

Comment: This would be very much easier to do with a scripting language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[see fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fd57/21)

```
select 
sum(case when name='Joe' then revenue else 0 end) as JOE,
sum(case when name='Bill' then revenue else 0 end) as Bill,
sum(case when name='Tim' then revenue else 0 end) as TIM

from client

union

select 
sum(case when name='Joe' then expense else 0 end) as JOE,
sum(case when name='Bill' then expense else 0 end) as Bill,
sum(case when name='Tim' then expense else 0 end) as TIM

from client
```

Comment: why a -1? it gives desired results ?

Comment: Vijaykumar, yes you are right it gives desired results, I do not know who gave -1.  I just gave +1.

Comment: that's because when you add many more data its becomes inefficient,but this is one way of doing it

Comment: @davidjhp you can try pivoting on this table,but iguess you dont see this output

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi unfortunately there's no avoiding hard coding names in case to get a pivot

Comment: Ok,then this is the only way of solving this kind of issues right sir ? @Bohemian

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi in mysql, yes. Some databases (eg (MSSQL) have native support for pivots, which allow columns to be created in the result without knowing the (in this case) names. Mysql, unfortunately doesn't have this. You could probably support dynamic names with a stored procedure that builds and executes dynamic SQL, but it would be ugly. This query could be improved a little, but at least as it is, it will work on all databases.

Comment: So what happens if you want to add a calculated field such as Gross Margin just below those 2? how would you do it?