# who visited the room

Tags: sql, transformation, rank

I have a table with `userid`, `roomid` and `timestamp` fields.

Each room may have different `userIds`:

```
 userId1 roomid1 12:15:17
 userId1 roomid1 12:17:15
 userId2 roomid1 13:17:15 
 userId3 roomid2 12:15:15
 userId4 roomid2 12:15:18
 userId5 roomid2 12:15:25
```

And I need a query that will return something like this:

```
  roomid            1           2           3        4           5
  roomid1      userid1       userid2     userid3
  roomid2      userid4       userid5     userid6   userid7    userid8
```

so i could see what distinct users visited what distinct rooms during the whole game.

There may be up to 32 users in the room.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: RDBMS matters here... but you're after a "dynamic pivot" ([SQL SERVER example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot)  or 32 case statements with a max grouping. ([mySQL case example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320631/how-to-pivot-a-table-in-mysql-using-case-statements))

Comment: those things are possible in some RDBMS, but in my opinion, it's much better to do it on the client-side if you have one

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT roomid, [userId1] AS userId1, [userId2] AS userId2, [userId3] AS userId3, [userId4] AS userId4, [userId5] AS userId5
FROM (SELECT timestamp, userid, roomid
      FROM yourtable) a
PIVOT
(COUNT (timestamp) 
 FOR userid IN ([userId1], [userId2], [userId3], [userId4], [userId5])
) AS b
ORDER BY b.roomid;
```

OUTPUT:

```
roomid  userId1 userId2 userId3 userId4 userId5
roomid1 2       1       0       0       0
roomid2 0       0       1       1       1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7df741/1/0

Comment: i have about 500 user ids how can i do it without specifying each of them. also i don't need how many times he has been to the room just who so it shoul look like


      roomid            1                 2              3            4              5
      roomid1      userid1       userid2     userid3
      roomid2      userid4       userid5     userid6   userid7    userid8

Comment: As above, use a dynamic pivot, or specify them all.

Comment: check the discription example